# Наложение элементов друг на друга в Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

`MainActivity.xml`, пытаюсь сделать в нем подключаемый `toolbar_layout` с тулбаром и `content_main`, собственно содержащий контент.

**Происходит наложение**

[image: Наложение]

**Код MainActivity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.project.project.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Код ContentMain**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ru.project.project.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="13245678934523234234" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Как сделать один `include` под другим?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы контент отображался нормально необходимо было добавить такие строчку в главный layout `content_main`

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```